# Bounded sequence in $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$ in 1D

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, sobolev-spaces

Let $\Omega = [0,1]$ for simplicity. Take a sequence $\{u_{n}\}$ which is bounded in $W^{1,1}(\Omega)$. Then up to a subsequence we have there exists $u$ such that $u_{n} \rightharpoonup u$ weak-* in $L^{\infty}(\Omega)$. However does it necessarily mean that:

1. $u$ is continuous?
2. $u_{n} \to u$ uniformly? i.e. $$\sup_{x \in \Omega}|u_{n}(x)-u(x)| \to 0 $$ as $n \to \infty$.

My thoughts:

I know that the $u_{n}$ are all uniformly continuous by Sobolev embedding. My gut feeling is that the statement shouldn't be true, i think a counterexample like a sequence which converges to $sgn(x)$ might work but to be honest I am getting a bit confused between the different notions of convergence. I would appreciate any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take $u_n(x)=nx$ for $-\frac1n\le x\le\frac1n$, $u_n=-1$ for $x\le-\frac1n$ and $u_n=1$ for $x\ge\frac1n$, you have that $u_n^\prime=n\chi_{(-1/n,1/n)}$ and $|u_n|\le 1$, so the sequence is bounded in $W^{1,1}$. The weak limit is discontinuous. $u(0)=0$, $u=-1$ for $x<0$ and $u=1$ for $x>0$.  Since the sequence of continuous functions converges pointwise to a discontinuous function, you cannot have uniform convergence.

Comment: Ah yes I see. So the function can indeed converge to a discontinuous function and that's what kills uniform convergence. It should also be possible to construct a sequence which does the same thing but is also smooth right? I guess by mollifying or something similar to $\{tan(nx)\}_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$.

Comment: Yes. You could mollify $u_n^\prime $ to make it smooth and then take the primitive.

Comment: Thanks for your answer